# how signals in a SoC are connected at PAD to reach the TOP

Tags: verilog, microcontroller, register-transfer-level

How are signals/ports of peripheral in a microcontroller connected to the PAD ??
Say, my SoC has 'n' signals. then these 'n' signals will be connected to pad and then reach the top-level. How is this connection done ?

Answer (score 0):

Pad connections are made by HDL wires as with any other connection. Those wires would traverse hierarchical boundaries until they reach the pads which are instantiated cells like any other*. Some pads require more than one connection (for output signals, input signals, output enables and/or direction controls). Between your peripheral and the pad there may be additional SoC logic for pad functional multiplexing, test mode multiplexing, debug and/or jtag/scan test structures.

A typical (simplified) hierarchy may look like:

- top

  - core

    - processor
    - system_logic
    - peripheral_1
    - peripheral_N
    - subsystem_M
  - io

    - pad_X

      - funcmux_X
      - testmux_X
      - jtag_X
      - pad_cell_X
    - pad_Y
    - pad_Y

A peripheral peripheral_1 may be hooked to pad_X, requiring 1 wire for a straight output or input pad, or 2 wires for a tristate-able output pad, or 3 for a bidirectional pad, or more for more complex electrical configurations of the pad. That bundle of N wires would travel up the Verilog hierarchy from peripheral_1 to top and down to the required pad logic, via any additional logic controlling pad multiplexing or test. The hierarchy above is just one example.

In an SoC, that's a lot of wires in total, and is very error-prone to do manually. An automated EDA IP assembly tool can be used.

*In standard-cell SoC design flows, the pad is just another cell.
The exact arrangement may be dictated by your cell library and/or physical design flow.

Comment: thanks :) 
This is pretty much what I was looking for... well explained